# How to share image (File Path) with content using share Intent in all devices

Tags: java, android

I am downloading image and taking it filepath to share but it is not working on all platforms except whatsapp. While it is showing can't upload image on insta and file not attached on gmail.

```
 `private void genericShare(Activity activity) { 
       Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
       shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, downloadedFilesPath); 
       shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
       shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getClipBoardText(activity)); 
       activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, 
       activity.getResources().getText(R.string.share_using))); 
       }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following demo app code, after clone it just change the hardcoded file path.

https://github.com/nikkulshrestha/imageShare